# How to use multiple COUNT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I have `task`, every `task` have `state`.

```
1 - planned
2 - executing
3 - finished
```

I want get count of all planned, executing and finished `task`.

I can write three queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `task` WHERE state = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `task` WHERE state = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `task` WHERE state = 3
```

So, my question is: It is possible (and how?) get this data in one query?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another approach is to use group by, like this:

```
select state, count(*)
from task
group by state
```

Comment: of course.. funny how we can easily forget other methods aye!

Answer (score 5):

you use SUM

```
select state,
sum(case when state = 1 then 1 else 0 end) state1count,
sum(case when state = 2 then 1 else 0 end) state2count,
sum(case when state = 3 then 1 else 0 end) state3count
from task
```